# Wordpress - Image href for home menu nav not working

Tags: php, css, html

I have an image linked to a li element from a navbar in wordpress.

All is working fine but when i hover mouse on image, it also shows a menu element hover in the list.

How can i hide that when it is linked to the image?

This is the php code for that (from nav-menu-template.php):

```
if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
return "<li id='menu-item-1000' class='menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1000'><a class='logo' href='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo'><img style='position:absolute;top:-20px;left:-125px;z-index:200;max-width: 402%; ' src='http://razvanwork.esy.es/exelo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/LogoPrelucrat.png' alt='Exelo' ></a></li>".$items;
```

I attach an image to show what it is doing: [image]

Comment: "This is the php code for that (from nav-menu-template.php):" -- have you hacked a Core file? There is already a close vote on this question, probably as "pure CSS" which was my first thought too. I am not voting to close right now but please add a better explanation of the problem with more detail, including ___your___ code.

Comment: i haven't hacked anythink, man. i don't understand why are you talking like that. close it, do what you want, but with that attitude you're not doing something good. i already put there the code that i added to that file ( nav-menu-template.php ), to add manually something i needed.

Comment: You misunderstand. [`nav-menu-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L0) is a WordPress Core file. If you have "added to that file", as you say you have, you have hacked a Core file. You should not be editing Core files in any way. I think you need a custom walker. Maybe one of these questions/answer will help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+walker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class used for your navigation menu's anchor tag has a css selector `:hover`. Because the image logo has been added withing the anchor tag, it is considered a part of the link and the hover styling affects it as if it were any other link in your nav menu.

### Solutions

- Find another way to add the logo image to your site.
- Use a different class for this particular anchor tag that is used by the rest of the navigation menu.
- Add a unique class to this anchor tag and reset the styling for the `:hover` selector. The most visible styling here is probably the `backgound-color` property, but refer to your nav menu's `:hover` styling to determine the properties being used.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, I managed to fix it by adding position:relative on the a href linked to the image and after that i moved it with left:-10px. Thanks again. :)